# Finding a possibly deleted user account profile page

Tags: support, profile-page, new-users, users

Where is the "about" page for user8680478?

If "my" URL is:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/177328/thufir

I tried:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/8680478

but that just gives me a 404 error. Either the meta or "regular" Stack Overflow user page.

---

Here:

*[how to enter into an infinite loop of expect operations with Tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729447/how-to-enter-into-an-infinite-loop-of-expect-operations-with-tcl)*

You can see a comment by this user, so they do or did exist. But there's no clickable link.

Comment: I don't get the regular mod deleted user page either. I wonder if the user ever existed...

Comment: I added a link to a comment by that user, whose name I copied/pasted here.

Comment: That's in SO... Which has more users. A lot more users... You will still get a 404 for a deleted user.

Comment: okay.  but the basic idea is ../users/#### and that should bring up their profile?

Comment: If the user was deleted or never existed you will get a 404. I tested with both

Comment: People delete their profile for a reason: they don't want to be part of the place any more, and surely don't want to be contacted about/from that place. So even if there was a way to see deleted user's profile page, we should avoid using it in order to contact the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've forgotten (or didn't know) something - user IDs are per-site. Every user gets an ID every time they create a profile on a site - a "profile" is a single instance of someone's account on a site. So you can't take someone's user ID number from SO and then try to find their profile on another site. It doesn't work that way.

In addition, you have an "account ID" and that's network wide but it's only ever really visible in a handful of places, most notably on your network profile on stackexchange.com. For example, your URL on your network profile is `https://stackexchange.com/users/96769/thufir` - which makes your account ID 96769, which is not your MSE user ID (177328) or Stack Overflow user ID (262852).

The username you're seeing is "user8680478" that's not the account ID, that's their profile's user ID on Stack Overflow - they had the user number 8680478. So, if you wanted to see that user's profile page, you have to use Stack Overflow, not MSE - `https://stackoverflow.com/users/8680478`. That said, it won't show you anything different because only mods and staff can see deleted user stubs. And, as far as I can tell, that user never has had a profile on MSE.

As to why you can't see the about me page - when someone requests their profile be deleted... we really delete it. The about me page doesn't exist and none of the info that was on it is retained.

Answer (score 5):

That user dosen't exist yet. At the time of this post, the latest MSE uid was in the 7805x range. If you go to the users page, pick new and Creation date, you see the newest user. They would have a profile. Increment the number by 1 and you could see what you see.

I also tested with a freshly deleted spammer to cover the case of a previously existing user

Regular users get 404 for both deleted and non existent users... Mod view will show some additional information for the former.